# Function to convert POSIXct to Date class

Tags: r, lubridate, purrr

Hello I am trying to write a function that takes in a dataframe, and that will convert all POSIXct or POSIXlt types to Date type in R. I have created part of the function, but I am stuck on iterating over the elements at each index.

```
#Basic Data Frame
patientID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
AdmDate <- as.POSIXct(c('2010-10-11','2008-3-25','2016-4-23','2011-6-12'))
diabetes <- c("Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2")
status <- c("Poor", "Improved", "Excellent", "Poor")
patientdata <- data.frame(patientID, AdmDate, diabetes, status)


convertallPOSIXct <- function(data){
 if(getdata[[is.POSIXt()=='TRUE']])
   getdata[[]] <- class(as.Date()) 
}

getdata <- function(x) {
  chr_test <- x %>%
    map_chr(~ paste(class(.), collapse = "/"))
}
```

The get data function seems to work, but I am not sure how to take each element from getdata and transform it to a Date class in R. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here's one option with `lapply`:

```
df <- patientdata

df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {
    if (inherits(x, "POSIXt")) as.Date(x) else x
})

str(df)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ patientID: num  1 2 3 4
#  $ AdmDate  : Date, format: "2010-10-11" "2008-03-25" ...
#  $ diabetes : chr  "Type1" "Type2" "Type1" "Type2"
#  $ status   : chr  "Poor" "Improved" "Excellent" "Poor"
```

The `[]` is necessary to preserve the `data.frame` structure, else you would end up with an ordinary list. Using `inherits` instead of `class(object) == "some_class"` is preferred because if the object has multiple classes -- which `POSIXt` objects *do* -- you still get a single logical result:

```
class(patientdata[,2]) == "POSIXt"
#[1] FALSE  TRUE

inherits(patientdata[,2], "POSIXt")
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Wonder what you did `df <- patientdata` part for though

Comment: I was just getting annoyed at typing `patientdata`.

Comment: In the computers era we are usually using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> instead of manually writing stuff :)

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to write it other than with the [] at the front? Just seems a bit hacky for a solution. Thanks so much for the solution! I was wondering if it would be easier to test using is.POSIXt in lubridate.

Comment: I don't personally see the `[]` is hacky; you could use `df <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) { if (inherits(x, "POSIXt")) as.Date(x) else x }))` but I prefer the former. Also, I don't know if `is.POSIXt` is significantly "easier", but it certainly introduces an unnecessary dependency.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `purrr` and `lubridate`, you could just write

```
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

patientdata <- data.frame(
    patientID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    AdmDate = as.POSIXct(c("2010-10-11", "2008-03-25", "2016-04-23", "2011-06-12")),
    diabetes = c("Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2"),
    status = c("Poor", "Improved", "Excellent", "Poor")
)

patientdata %>% modify_if(is.POSIXt, as.Date)
```

which will return something that looks the same as the original, but with the classes changed as you can see if you call `str` on it:

```
patientdata %>% modify_if(is.POSIXt, as.Date) %>% str()
#> 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ patientID: num  1 2 3 4
#>  $ AdmDate  : Date, format: "2010-10-11" "2008-03-25" "2016-04-23" ...
#>  $ diabetes : Factor w/ 2 levels "Type1","Type2": 1 2 1 2
#>  $ status   : Factor w/ 3 levels "Excellent","Improved",..: 3 2 1 3
```

Note that you need `modify` so `purrr` will keep the list a data.frame, and the `*_if` version, which takes a predicate function to determine which columns/elements to call the main function on.

If you don't want to use `lubridate` just for `is.POSIXt`, you could equivalently write

```
patientdata %>% modify_if(~'POSIXt' %in% class(.x), as.Date)
```

or the `dplyr` version:

```
library(dplyr)

patientdata %>% mutate_if(~'POSIXt' %in% class(.x), as.Date)
```

which with `lubridate::is.POSIXt` is as nice as the original:

```
patientdata %>% mutate_if(is.POSIXt, as.Date)
```

Comment: Hmm, I think your original code does work, but when I try to run it without the str() at the end I still seem to see a POSIXt object.....thoughts?patientdata %>% mutate_if(is.POSIXt, as.Date)
str(patientdata)

Comment: You need to chain in the `str`, i.e. `patientdata %>% mutate_if(is.POSIXt, as.Date) %>% str()` so `str` is called on the inherited data.frame. If you prefer, you could just assign the altered data.frame to a variable first, and then you can call `str` however you like: `patientdata2 <- patientdata %>% mutate_if(is.POSIXt, as.Date) ; str(patientdata2)`

Comment: patientdata <- patientdata %>% mutate_if(is.POSIXt, as.Date)
str(patientdata)
is a good syntax. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! As a note, as an alternative to `str`, if you use [`tibble`s](https://github.com/hadley/tibble/) (which you might as well, given you're already using tidyverse packages), the print method will automatically show the variable classes at the top of each column: `patientdata %>% as_data_frame() %>% mutate_if(is.POSIXt, as.Date)`

Comment: After looking through the documentation for mutate_if, do you think I could use it to replace spaces in multiple column headers? I am trying to read in some files, all which have spaces or a character in the header that makes it hard to work with, and seems like it should be doable with mutate and chaining, rather than 5 lines for each file. Probably should start a new thread for this..

Comment: `mutate` is to add or change columns, not rename them. You could use `rename` or `select`, but I'd start with just `make.names`, which clears out a lot of the common problems for you. And yeah, this is a new question, though I think there was another like it a day or so ago, if you search.

Comment: If I wanted to create a function to do this, does this look remotely right? This is my first stab at a function with mutate_if. convertPOSIX <- function(df) {
  for (i in 1:length(colnames(df))) {
   df[i] <<- mutate_if(is.POSIXt[i], as.Date()[i])
  }
  return(df)
}

Comment: a. dplyr functions take and return data.frames; b. avoid `<<-` if possible; c. loops are not usually the best way to do things in R. In this case, if you want to make it a function, all you need is `convertPOSIX <- function(df){df %>% mutate_if(is.POSIXt, as.Date)}`, though that's not necessarily a very useful function unless you're going to call it on a lot of data.frames.

Comment: So it is; this is an old answer. Updated.